# Paste data from excel with read.delim and forcing column to numeric

Tags: r

I found out the option of read.delim to paste data from xlsx faster. So I came across the next problem.

As you can see the p.value is with the comma, by default is converting the vector in character, I want it as numeric  (or integer, whatever the difference is). I could change it in Excel but I stick with doing it in R, and I wanted to do it without sub "," by ".". So I was trying kind of:

```
# the column "Var" is character but the p.value is numeric

pvalue <- read.delim(header = T, "clipboard", colClasses = c("character", "integer"))
```

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: In  `read.delim` set `sep=","`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pvalue <- read.delim(header = TRUE, "clipboard", dec = ",")
```